# remove record from a struct according to condition

Tags: ios, struct, swift3

I have a `struct` define as:

```
struct Section {
 var name: String!
 var items: [String]!

 init(name: String, items: [String]) {
    self.name = name
    self.items = items
 }
}
```

Now how can I filter this struct according to number of items in record. Say I wanna remove every record if items is nil

e.g.

```
sections = [
        Section(name: "Mac", items: ["MacBook", "MacBook Air", "MacBook Pro", "iMac", "Mac Pro", "Mac mini", "Accessories", "OS X El Capitan"]),

        Section(name: "iPad", items: []), // no Items in this record (remove this)

        Section(name: "iPhone", items: ["iPhone 6s", "iPhone 6", "iPhone SE", "Accessories"]),

]
```

The above data have 3 records where record #2 ("iPad") don't have any items so how can I remove it from my struct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all don't declare `items` as implicit unwrapped optional since you are using an initializer which expects a non-optional.

The benefit is that you need to check only for emptiness rather than additionally for `nil`

```
let filteredSections = sections.filter { !$0.items.isEmpty }
```